# How to pull updates from a remote (bare) master repo at Bitbucket to a local bare master repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bare

First, a (bare) master repo with the name "test" is created in Bitbucket.

Then, a local bare master repo is created on a node with the ip `10.0.0.1`:

```
git clone --bare https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git
```

Then, a local working repo is created on a node with the ip `10.0.0.253`:

```
git clone ssh://username2@10.0.0.1:/home/username2/test.git
```

Thus, the work flow within `10.0.0.x` is :

```
(1) code on 10.0.0.253 
(2) at 10.0.0.253, git push to 10.0.0.1
(3) at 10.0.0.1, git push to Bitbucket
```

Suppose a local working repo is created outside `10.0.0.x`, say `50.113.23.x`, and directly from Bitbucket:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test.git
```

The work flow there is :

```
(1) code on 50.113.23.x
(2) at 50.113.23.x, git push to Bitbucket
```

Now, could you help to comment how to pull updates from the Bitbucket repo to the local bare master repo at `10.0.0.1` ? The following complains `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`:

```
git pull origin master
```

The following finishes, but a subsequent `git log` shows no commits from `50.113.23.x`:

```
 git fetch origin master
```

Could you help to comment the workaround here ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

I.e. explicitly update the local `master`.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer ! Could you help to comment where could I learn such knowledge from ?

Comment: Start [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Git) and follow tutorials, docs and books. Full disclosure — I am the author of that wiki page. :-) And of course a lot of painful practise.

Comment: Thank you very much again !